# Cholesky factorization: prove that $\|R\|=\|R^*\|=\|A^{1/2}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd need proof of the fact that $\|R\|=\|R^*\|=\|A^{1/2}\|$ where $R$ is the upper triangular matrix (with conjugate-transpose $R^*$) given by the Cholesky factorization of $A$. My book hinted to use SVD for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Frobenius norm, $\|X\|:=\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(XX^\ast)}\equiv\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(X^\ast X)}$.

For induced 2-norm, i.e. the largest singular value, $\|X\|=\sigma_1(X)=\sqrt{\rho(XX^\ast)}\equiv\sqrt{\rho(X^\ast X)}$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes spectral radius.

All the above expressions depend on $XX^\ast$ or $X^\ast X$. Since $RR^\ast=(R^\ast)^\ast (R^\ast) = (A^{1/2})(A^{1/2})^\ast = A$, we conclude that $R,\,R^\ast$ and $A^{1/2}$ have equal Frobenius norms or induced 2-norms.

The norms of the three matrices may be different if some other kinds of matrix norms are used.